# How to turn a large PDF's pages to images efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, pdf, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint to receive a PDF with many pages.

The client takes photos of several documents, turns them into one PDF, and sends them to this endpoint.

This endpoint should convert every page back to an image and do some processing on it, this should obviously be done in the background.

What is the most efficient way to do this?
I have tried pdf2image, but as their documentation says,

> A relatively big PDF will use up all your memory and cause the process to be killed

Comment: Split the PDF into individual pages and use `pdf2image` on them one at a time.

Comment: That documentation was written a generation ago, when machines had memory in the megabytes.  You can safely use `pdf2image` for this.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried it just now and it used over 5 Gigabytes of RAM and kept running for over 100 seconds, I had to kill the process.

Comment: @MattDMo pdf2image works on an entire file, how can I use it with individual pages?

Comment: @KJ They are not images of text.

Comment: I don't know why my question was closed.
The question from 13 years ago doesn't even answer my question, but still, my question has other parts to it, like how to do this in the background using FastAPI.
I definitely don't think this question should have been closed.